# SQL Schema compare - column level actions

Tags: sql-server, schema-compare

I have a production DB and a dev DB. I'd like SOME of the Dev DB changes to be propagated to the Production DB. The production DB also has some new columns and changes due to bug fixing. I need a Scema Compare Tool that allows for acccepting/deniyng changes at the column level.

I have tried the VS2010 Schema Compare, but it seems one can't change the Update Action at the column level... Tried Red Gate SQL Compare 9, same, can't edit changes at the column level either.

I suspect I'll have to manually modify the update script generated by one of those two.

What is a recommended way to deal with this? VS2010 or Red Gate vs another tool?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Red Gate's tools for this are the gold standard. Command line options might let you customize the scripts to the level you need.

Edit: Red Gate SQL compare makes it pretty easy to pick and choose your changes:
If you right click on the differences shown in the bottom pane you can show the script, which is easy to copy, paste, then edit. I understand this isn't automated, but it's very flexible through the UI.

Of course, the Synchronization Wizard will happily generate a well commented script too.

Still, if you want to automate to the column level, use the command line options, and then something else to modify your resulting scripts.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Compare 9.5 (current available as a beta) lets you edit the default generated script and when committed to source control (via SQL Source Control 3), will re-use the customizations in future deployments.

http://www.red-gate.com/MessageBoard/viewtopic.php?t=14113